# Close only Word.Application Objects that were created by my program

Tags: ms-access, vba, parent-child, ms-word

So I'm working on a VBA function in Access 2010 that creates a Word.Application object and returns it. Later on I want to be able to close this object, however not if its a Word.Application object that was not started by my program.

```
    Public myGlobalWordApp as Object
    Public newWordAppInstCreated as Boolean

    Function GetWordAppInstance(Optional isVisible As Boolean = False) As Object
        newWordAppInstCreated = False
        On Error Resume Next
        Set myGlobalWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        If myGlobalWordApp = Nothing Then
            myGlobalWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            myGlobalWordApp.Visible = isVisible
            newWordAppInstCreated = True
        End If

        Set GetWordAppInstance = myGlobalWordApp

    End Function
```

I want to make a CloseWordAppInstance() Sub that closes the myGlobalWordApp application object BUT ONLY if my VBA code was the one to open it. Sometimes I'll have another Word document up that I'm looking at and I don't want that window to be closed.

I've looked at the Word 2010 Application documentation and I saw that there is a .Parent method that I can call. I imagine that I could use this to see if I can determine if my Access Document/Module/Application created the Word.Application object but I dont know how to reference the "current object" or know how to do the comparison. Any help on that step would be appreciated.

My only "impropper" way of doing this would be checking the Boolean flags that I attempted to make, but that wont work if I make a second object.

Alternatively if anyone knows a better way to do this process that would be great!

Comment: I like you solution but what do you mean by that: `but that wont work if I make a second object`? in you code there are two errors: 1. use `myGlobalWordApp is Nothing` instead of `myGlobalWordApp = Nothing` and 2. add `set` before one line to have `Set myGlobalWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")`

Comment: If you want to create multiple instances then use a Global Collection to store the references to the instances you opened.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that after you have created a word instance, you keep its reference. You can then use the same reference to close the word instance.

```
Private myGlobalWordApp As Object

Public Function GetWordAppInstance(Optional isVisible As Boolean = False) As Object
    On Error GoTo ErrH
    If myGlobalWordApp Is Nothing Then
        '' create a new word instance if one doesn't exist
        Set myGlobalWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        myGlobalWordApp.Visible = isVisible
        Set GetWordAppInstance = myGlobalWordApp
    Else
        '' otherwise return the instance we have
        Set GetWordAppInstance = myGlobalWordApp
    End If
    Exit Function
ErrH:
    MsgBox "Error creating word instance!", vbExclamation
End Function

Public Sub CloseWordInstance()
    If Not myGlobalWordApp Is Nothing Then
        '' close our word instance
        myGlobalWordApp.Quit False
        Set myGlobalWordApp = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

You should never need to use the `myGlobalWordApp` variable directly. You can instead call the `GetWordAppInstance` to get the word instance and the `CloseWordInstance` to safely close it. This would ensure that you don't ever overwrite the `myGlobalWordApp` variable and lose reference to the word instance.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim myWordInst As Object, wdDoc As Object

    Set myWordInst = GetWordAppInstance(True)
    Set wdDoc = myWordInst.Documents.Add

    ' do something with this doc here

    CloseWordInstance

End Sub
```